# Schedule a task after deployment

Tags: tfs, msbuild, scheduled-tasks, msdeploy

I need to setup a scheduled task in Windows Task Scheduler (v2.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2) right after my web site deploys.

I am using TFS 2010 to build my application, and apparently my MSBuild Arguments contain arguments `/P:DeployOnBuild=True /P:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish /P:CreatePackageOnPublish=true /P:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSvc`.

I know that I can use `Schtasks.exe` to setup a scheduled task via command line, I also know there is a `runCommand` provider for MsDeploy. So I thought I could use `runCommand` to run `Schtasks.exe` with required parameters.

My question is how I do it in TFS and MsBuild. I assumed I could pass some parameters to MsBuild, and they would be transferred "as is" to MsDeploy, but I could not find how I do it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

If it *must* be after the build, you'll need to use the [`postSync` msdeploy argument](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to execute a `runCommand`. Since `postSync` is not available from Visual Studio's MSBuild tasks, you'll need to generate a package and then run the generated `cmd` file with the `postSync` argument tacked onto the end.

```
Package.cmd -postSync:runCommand="c:\windows\system32\schtasks.exe arguments"
```

If it *should* be after the build, you can include an additional provide by adding the following to your publish profile (`pubxml`), `.wpp.targets` file or your project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="runCommand">
    <Path>&quot;c:\Windows\system32\schtasks.exe&quot; &quot;Arguments here&quot;</Path>
  </MsDeploySourceManifest>
</ItemGroup>
```

It's not officially guarantees that providers run in order, but in practise they do. You might need to hook a target into the right event, though, so you can register your `runCommand` *after* the other providers.

Comment: Thanks. I indeed do not care much about the order. I'll try your approach, and then accept.